# How to retrieve POST request body before proxying it

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect, node-http-proxy

Using [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) library on Node, I tried to retrieve request body before proxying it with [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy).

Since Node v4, we have to use some middleware like bodyParser (or just *data*/*end* events on request) to retrieve POST request body.

Problem is, it seems to *consume* the request stream, and the request timeout when being proxied.

Here is the code, first I retrieve the body with *data* event, then I give it to http-proxy, but the request timeouts.

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var connect = require('connect');

var proxy = new httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9015
  }
});

var app = connect()
  .use(function (req, res, next) {
    var bodyBuffer = '';

    req.on('data', function (data) {
      bodyBuffer += data;
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
      req.body = buffer;

      next();
    });
  })
  .use(function (req, res) {

    //I can use req.body now
    //But the proxy request timeouts
    proxy.web(req, res);
  });

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the stream is read to retrieve request body, it can not be sent a second time when proxying the request.

To do so, there is an option on http-proxy `web()` method to send an already buffered request.

On the first middleware, construct a `PassThrough` stream with a buffer containing the body you retrieve. Store it on the request for example (there might be better ways to store it), for later use.

```
var stream = require('stream');

req.on('end', function() {
  req.body = buffer;

  var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
  bufferStream.end(new Buffer(buffer));
  req.bodyStream = bufferStream;

  next();
});
```

Then add it on the third parameter of `proxy.web()` call, on the `buffer` property.

```
proxy.web(req, res, {buffer: req.bodyStream});
```

Comment: I saw a lot of similar answers for similar questions and this is the best one!
The rest of the answers I found said to either not use body-parses or proxy the request prior to using. This overcomes it.